# can i install the Nokia 5230 OS for Nokia 5228 Phone?

Tags: mobile, nokia

Am using Nokia 5228 phone. I want to install the other Phone OS like Nokia 5230. Is this possible or Not?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is impossible to achieve. Since the Sw is different for different phones.

Even though two phones appears to look same in functionality, obviously they will have some different functionality some where.. [Either in GUI or in the back end].

As well as, the device S/w are designed as to recognize the particular mobile phones for which they are made for [by serial number/ model number or may be anything else only.]

Also you'll have to get the S/w first which is very difficult to get.

You ca not change anything in the device so that the device gets other phone's S/w.

So conclusion is:

You CAN NOT install the Nokia 5230 OS for Nokia 5228 Phone.